# What kind of rearrangement happens between 2,2,5-trimethylcyclopentanol and concentrated sulfuric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation, elimination

**Question**:

[image]

**My attempt:**

After getting the carbocation after protonation, in order to form a more stable alkene, it rearranged the methyl group on the adjacent carbon so as to get the alkene in the option (b). I am confused that whether it should be "1,2 hydride shift" or should it be "1,2 methyl shift" because the migratory aptitude of $\ce{H-}$ group is more than $\ce{CH3-}$ but here if carbocation formation is the RDS (considering E1) should we not rearrange it to a more stable species?

Comment: try considering the fact that 'b' is more substituted as compared to 'a'

Comment: Have a look into this https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/161776/115228

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hydride shift or Methyl shift](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/161776/hydride-shift-or-methyl-shift)